# PostGIS & QGIS 3.4 : convert mixed Linestring/Multilinestring geometry to multilinestring

Tags: postgis, geometry-conversion

I have a PostGIS table in which the geometries are mixed Linestring and Multilinestring. But QGIS doesn't like it very much (it splits the table by the different geometries in the "add PostGIS table" dialog for example).

I would like to have only multilinestring type. I tried converting the type with

```
ALTER TABLE LaTable
    ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(MULTILINESTRING, 31370)
```

but I got error

```
ERROR:  Geometry type (LineString) does not match column type (MultiLineString)
```

I even tried the other way around (multilinestring --> linestring) but I also got the error the other way around :

```
ERROR:  Geometry type (MultiLineString) does not match column type (LineString)
```

Is there an other way I could get a single-type geometry on this table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly cast the `linestring` to `multilinestring` using [`st_multi`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Multi.html)

```
ALTER TABLE LaTable
    ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(MULTILINESTRING, 31370) USING ST_Multi(geom);
```